# can i autorefresh my div using the php code i already have

Tags: php, refresh, reload

Is there a way to make a certain div autorefresh every minute or so, and not my whole page? Because it would take too long to reload the page every minute. The div itself is the important part which can change.

```
<div id="livetable">
<?php loadpage(); ?>
</div>

<?php
define('ELEMENT_CONTENT_ONLY', true);
define('ELEMENT_PRESERVE_TAGS', false);

function value_in($element_name, $xml, $content_only = true) 
{
    if ($xml == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    $found = preg_match('#<'.$element_name.'(?:\s+[^>]+)?>(.*?)'.'</'.$element_name.'>#s', $xml, $matches);
    if ($found != false) 
    {
        if ($content_only) 
        {
            return $matches[1];  //ignore the enclosing tags
        }
       else 
       {
            return $matches[0];  //return the full pattern match
        }
    }
    // No match found: return false.
    return false;
}

function loadpage()
{
      echo "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"width: 95%\" >";
      echo "<tr class=\"info-row\" bgcolor=#252525 style=\"color:white;  height: 15px;\">";
      echo "<td style=\"width: 14%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Preview</b></td>";
      echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Live</b></td>";
      echo "<td style=\"width: 36%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Stream</b></td>";
      echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Viewers</b></td>";
      echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; height: 10px; padding-left: 5px;\"><b>Time online</b></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      addrow(107473,10,"Osuryn","Osuryn is streaming random games live",false);
      addrow(210320,28,"Dennojj","Dennojj is streaming PS3 games",true);
      echo "</table>";
}

function addrow($streamID, $streamPage , $streamName , $streamSlogan, $odd)
{
     if ($odd)
     {
            echo "<tr class=\"content-row online\" id=\"958\" bgcolor=#A7A7A7>";
     }
     else
     {
            echo "<tr class=\"content-row online\" id=\"958\" bgcolor=#BFBFBF>";
     }
     echo "<td style=\"width: 14%;\"><img src=\"http://img.hw.own3d.tv/live/live_tn_".$streamID."_.jpg\" style=\"height: 72px;\" \></td>";
     echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; padding-left: 5px;\"><br><br><b>".getLiveStatus($streamID)."</b></td>";
     echo "<td style=\"width: 36%; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 6px;\">";
     echo "<div><br><a href=\"http://brokendiamond.org/?q=node/$streamPage\">$streamName</a></div>";
     echo "<div style=\"padding-top: 6px; font-size: 11px;\">$streamSlogan</div>";
     echo "</td>";
     echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; padding-left: 5px;\"><br><br>".getLiveViews($streamID)."</td>";
     echo "<td style=\"width: 10%; padding-left: 5px;\"><br><br>".getOnTime($streamID)." minutes online</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}

function getLiveStatus($streamID)
{
    $request =  'http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id='.$streamID;
    $arg = '240';

    $session = curl_init($request.$arg);

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);

    if (preg_match("/true/",$response, $result)) 
    {
        $streamStatus="Live";
    } 
    else 
    {
      $streamStatus="Offline";
    }
    return $streamStatus;
}

function getLiveViews($StreamID)
{
    $request =  'http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id='.$StreamID;
    $arg = '240';

    $session = curl_init($request.$arg);

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);

    $viewStatus =value_in('liveViewers', $response) + "";

    return $viewStatus;
}

function getOnTime($StreamID)
{
    $request =  'http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id='.$StreamID;
    $arg = '240';

    $session = curl_init($request.$arg);

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);

    $onStatus =value_in('LiveDuration', $response) + "";

    return $onStatus;
}
?>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: @Vyctor that would refresh the whole page (would achieve the req. effect if the div were an iframe, though). To refresh only a div he would need js (and an ajax call)

Comment: @DamienPirsy ah you're right, so it'll be different link :) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make `AJAX` request with JavaScript that'll update the `div` or use an `iframe`.

The simplest way to do this or maybe if you're not familiar with JavaScript, is to use an `iframe`. Basically what you need to do is have the content of the `div` loaded using the `iframe` and also modify the PHP code that's used within the `iframe` to reload the page after X seconds. This should be easy with PHP [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

If you're going to go with AJAX instead, you'll want to use the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) function to repeat a function call that will actually make the AJAX request and update the `div`'s content. However, it might be a good idea to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) instead and have the function call itself, by also using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) too of course after X seconds. The reason for that is because, by using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) JavaScript will continues to run even if the last operation has not yet finished. But if you were to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) JavaScript will wait for the last function call to finish before moving on to the next one.

Answer (score 3):

Not simply with PHP, no. But you can use AJAX to retrieve the data from an external file and update the contents of the div with JavaScript. Using jQuery:

```
$.get('/path/to/php/script', function(data) {
  $('#selector').html(data);
});
```

OR, more simply:

```
$('#selector').load('/path/to/php/script');
```

**Edit - clarification:**

File "ajax.php":

```
<?php

// Include your functions here
echo loadpage();
```

HTML file:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#livetable").load("ajax.php");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: is it possible to use my loadpage function in stead of a whole new script? it would just become copy paste tho, but it would make it a lot easyer for me

Comment: Yes. Just include that function on the page that you call via ajax, and return the response of the function as the page output.

Comment: @ Gary Chambers, what do i need to put in the #selector place? 
.load can be ('loadpage()'); right?

Comment: hmm i tried this, but it didn't work :s it doesn't show anything

Comment: It looks like your `loadpage` function is already echoing an output. Remove `echo` from the ajax.php line I've included above.

Comment: its fixed, i wrote a javascript with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

servers are not allowed to push content to the client via normal delivery of html.
Use an clientside ajax-request to fetch the new content for the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily refresh your whole page by using [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

You you want to refresh just on div, you'll going to need ajax, probably easiest solution is to to use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or just [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

**in php it is not possible to refresh particular div only entire page refresh is possible try this,, i f you want to do it in AJAX its possible using settimeout refresh **

//in php we have

header("refresh:5;url:tvinfo.php");

Comment: This would refresh the whole page, not just the div

Comment: @DamienPirsy , yes it is possible with jquery  $('div').get());setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload=2000;});